# My code works but wont simulate past the first two csv rows

Tags: python, computer-science, cs50

CS50x code for world-cup simulations:

every time i run the code, it doesn't go beyond the for two rows of my csv.

When i run the code with the women's team version i get the same error.

My code compiles and i get the percentage needed to pass the lab but i need to understand and probably fix the error.

""" Simulate a sports tournament"""

```
import csv
import sys
import random
""" Number of simulations to run
N = 1000

def main():
```

"""Ensure correct usage"""

```
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: python tournament.py FILENAME")
```

open csv file

```
    teams = []
    filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
for team in reader:
            team["rating"] = int(team["rating"])
            teams.append(team)
```

Simulate N tournaments and keep track of win counts

```
counts = {}
for c in range(N):
        winner = simulate_tournament(teams)
if winner in counts:
            counts[winner] += 1
else:
            counts[winner] = 1
```

Print each team's chances of winning, according to simulation

```
for team in sorted(counts, key=lambda team: counts[team], reverse=True):
print(f"{team}: {counts[team] * 100 / N:.1f}% chance of winning")
```

Simulate a game. Return True if team1 wins, False otherwise.

```
def simulate_game(team1, team2):

    rating1 = team1["rating"]
    rating2 = team2["rating"]
    probability = 1 / (1 + 10 ** ((rating2 - rating1) / 600))
return random.random() < probability
```

Simulate a round. Return a list of winning teams."""

```
def simulate_round(teams):

    winners = []
"""Simulate games for all pairs of teams"""
for i in range(0, len(teams), 2):
if simulate_game(teams[i], teams[i + 1]):
            winners.append(teams[i])
else:
            winners.append(teams[i + 1])
return winners
```

Simulate a tournament.

```
def simulate_tournament(teams):
"""Simulate a tournament. Return name of winning team."""
while len(teams) > 1:
        teams = simulate_round(teams)
return teams[0]["team"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "i get the same error" - what error? Your post doesn't contain any error messages or stack traces or similar...

Comment: did not find team Belgium
did not find team Germany

the code doesnt read past the first two rows of the csv file

Answer (score 0):

The code above won't run as-is. It has too many indentation errors. For example, here are several places that are not correctly indented after `def a_function():`. And the same after several branching statements: `if`, `for`, `while`, etc. Indentation is critical for Python. Most programmers use 4 spaces for each indentation level. I tried to clean-up, then realized my changes might change your code's behavior.

There are 2 possible problems:

1. You don't initialize `counts` dictionary with 0 values for all teams. So, if a team never wins, it's not added to the dictionary and not printed. Most of the time Japan and Russia won't win the Men's tournament once in 1000 trials. The same is true for Cameroon and Nigeria in the Women's tournament (although occasionally they might win).
2. Check indentation for code below. With this indentation, you loop over `simulate_tournament()` N times, but don't check `winner` until you have exited the loop. You only check the LAST winner.

```
    counts = {}   
    for c in range(N):   
            winner = simulate_tournament(teams)
    if winner in counts:
                counts[winner] += 1
    else:
                counts[winner] = 1
```